# raspberry pi zero w calls startx unknown command

Tags: raspbian, startx

I have a rasperry pi zero w with raspbian stretch installed on a 4gb micro sd card. when I log in it goes to the pi@rasperrypi~$ command prompt. When I type in startx it says "unknown command". Is this a problem with the micro sd card? Because I have heard you need more than 4gb to boot the gui, or somthing else?

Comment: altough 8gb is recommended, i'm not sure this is the core of your problem

Comment: As Mike implied, if you run `sudo apt install raspberrypi-ui-mods` to install the full Pixel desktop you'll be in unsupported territory. You could attempt `sudo apt install xorg` if you just want a minimal X desktop. Be sure to watch the available disk space if you run these commands.

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian Stretch with Desktop requires an sd card with a minimum size of 8GB. I tend to use 16GB sd cards.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

> The Raspbian with Desktop image contained in the ZIP archive is over
>   4GB in size, which means that these archives use features which are
>   not supported by older unzip tools on some platforms.

Answer (score 1):

*Adding Answer due to lack of ability to add comment to @CoderMike's answer*

It is important to note whether you have **RASPBIAN STRETCH WITH DESKTOP** installed or **RASPBIAN STRETCH LITE**.

**Stretch LITE** doesn't have a GUI installed, hence the **LITE**. If this is the environment you are booting into this could be the issue. The GUI doesn't exist.

*Note: I installed Startx on STRETCH LITE, and was unsuccessful (It wouldn't boot into GUI). I had to reinstall RASPBIAN WITH DESKTOP to successfully boot into the GUI*

**Stretch with Desktop**
It is recommended to use at least a 8gb SD card if you are using **Stretch with Desktop**. According to the [website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) it states.

> The Raspbian with Desktop image contained in the ZIP archive is over
>   4GB in size...

Since you have a 4GB SD Card, and the install of the OS is larger then 4GB. You may have a corrupt install of Raspbian on your SD card. Which may be causing your issues. I would recommend getting at least an 8GB SD Card and Install Stretch With Desktop.